# Collinearity among OLS regressors may inflate their variance, but can it also change their estimated value?

Tags: regression, multicollinearity

I've read that collinearity between independent variables in an OLS regression may inflate the variance of the OLS estimates.

But, can it also change their estimated value?

Comment: This hypothetical is a little difficult to comprehend: a change implies there was a starting condition (presumably, lack of collinearity) that was altered.  But how would that come about in these circumstances? How do you conceive of modifying the independent variables, exactly, and when you do, how would you preserve the meaning of their coefficients in a regression?  And, hypothetically assuming one could make sense of such a change, if collinearity never affected the estimates, how could it possibly affect their variance?

Comment: Totally on point. I guess the starting condition in my case is one what would expect from, say, experience. I know this is not satisfactory. Maybe I should have asked, more directly, does the presence of collinearity impact the variance of regressors and their estimated values/signs. Likely not, as the estimates are still unbiased?

Comment: One way I can interpret this question is to imagine an experiment in which the researcher is able to set the values of two variables. This enables her to run a sequence of observations in which those variables might be uncorrelated or a different sequence, of the same length, in which they are correlated. If we impose some restrictions on the ranges of those variables--for instance, maybe we will insist both variables have the same variances in both sequences--then we might have a meaningful way to compare the two situations. But we can't guarantee the sequences will give identical estimates!